# crontab won't run os.system python command

Tags: python, cron

Using ubuntu's 16.04 crontab and @reboot to run python3 script.  The script runs properly on reboot as I see the logged output.  However, my script's os.system command is not running.  It runs fine if ran outside of crontab.  My scripts are all executable.

crontab -l output:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot nohup /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/path/scheduler.py >> /path/log.out &
```

scheduler.py code:

```
#...(check if web server is running...if not restart)
os.system('nohup /usr/bin/python3 -u /path/webserver/main.py &')
print('this function ran')
```

When I logged the output of the os.system command , there was no output.

As a side note, I am running python schedule commands to check the general health of a webserver.  crontab doesn't seem to be the right tool for this so I just use crontab to start my python scheduler on reboot.

I am using flask as the webserver, and would use gunicorn and systemctrl if I could get it to work... but it didn't so this is my workaround.

Comment: Even if you figure out the answer, this seems like trouble down the road. Instead of troubleshooting a home brewed solution, I would suggest you troubleshoot the issues you were having with a more standard solution (either supervisord or systemctl). What kind of problems were you having with those?

Comment: @MrName, you are probably right.  This seemed like it would be an easy fix to hold me over until I come back to supervisord/systemctl.  With those two, and gunicorn, it was problem after problem.  Enough for me to try and find a simpler solution (like python schedule).

Comment: I get it for sure, been there, and it can be very frustrating. Let me know if you want help troubleshooting that stuff and I will do my best.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that, the command called by os.system is not in default path.

For example, tcpdump is not in /usr/bin/.

So, you can solve the problem by adding the full path of the command.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue when we try to run python script directly in crontab it just by passes the `os.system()` commands.

Make *launcher.sh*:

```sh
#!bin/bash
cd /home/pi/
sudo python example.py
```

Then, make your script executable:

```sh
chmod 755 launcher.sh
```

And at last, add your script to crontab:

```sh
crontab -e
```

and add this line at the end:

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/launcher.sh
(I set the program to run at each reboot)
```